# what happen to the current transaction when kubernetes container goes down

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kubernetes

I have a distributed scheduler. Now I have to pick the record and process them.
In my case, I will create a transaction and process the record.

Now suppose during the processing itself the Kubernetes container goes down. IN that case, what will happen does it release the lock and rollback the transaction

Comment: What scheduler are you using?

Comment: Spring boot scheduler

Answer (score 1):

When a pod should be terminated:

A SIGTERM signal is sent to the main process (PID 1) in each container, and a “grace period” countdown starts (defaults to 30 seconds - see below to change it).

Upon the receival of the SIGTERM, each container should start a graceful shutdown of the running application and exit.

If a container doesn’t terminate within the grace period, a SIGKILL signal will be sent and the container violently terminated.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: test
spec:
    replicas: 1
    template:
        spec:
            containers:
              - name: test
                image: ...
            terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
```

So in your spring boot app you need to handle the SIGTERM signal and rollback any transaction or persistent it outside for retrying it later.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So we have to explicitly handle those transactions.
My understanding is that when the container down.. then all the transactions are rollback and the lock is released. Is not that the case?

Comment: I wish spring would have done it automatically..but I don't think it does it..btw it's noting specific to kubernetes